# How to add index in descending order on a column in androidx room?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, android-room

Let's say I have an entity users --

```
@Entity()
class Users(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String
)
```

Now I want to create a composite index on this entity (table) like this (firstName DESC, lastName DESC). I can do this with sqlite command like this --

```
CREATE INDEX index_Users_firstName_lastName ON Users(firstName DESC, lastName DESC)
```

But I'm not able to do this with indices property in @Entity annotation. I tried doing this --

```
@Entity(indices = [Index("firstName DESC", "lastName DESC")])
class Users(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String
)
```

But it results in the following compiler error -- error: firstName DESC referenced in the index does not exists in the entity.

Is it possible to create an index in descending order on a column in room?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: No. I don't think its possible with room :(

Answer (score 1):

Defining the sort order of an indexed column in Room's `Entity` annotation is possible like this:

**Java**

```java
@androidx.room.Entity(
        tableName = "Users",
        indices = {
                @Index(
                        value = {"firstName", "lastName"},
                        orders = {Index.Order.ASC, Index.Order.DESC}
                )
        }
)
```

**Kotlin**

```kotlin
@androidx.room.Entity(
    tableName = "Users",
    indices = [
        Index(
            value = ["firstName", "lastName"],
            orders = [Index.Order.ASC, Index.Order.DESC]
        )
    ]
)
```